# Is there a Stack Overflow equivalent for design pattern topics?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I see more programming issues but not many architecture issues. Is there such a forum where design patterns are discussed?

Comment: Design patterns are patterns of -- you guessed it -- design. So this is programming, not architecture.

Comment: [oh hai there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101875/what-are-some-programming-questions-or-mistakes-you-get-wrong-only-as-you-get-b/2776764#2776764)

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to discuss architecture issues here (providing you're not talking about the architecture of homes and other buildings). Architectural issues are certainly "of interest to other programmers" so fall within the guidelines:

- detailed and specific
- written clearly and simply
- of interest to other programmers

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: :: Feelin meta?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns

> ### 2,749
>
> questions tagged
>   <sub>`[design-patterns]`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, architecture/design pattern questions are ok here.  This question however belongs on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are a programming topic, so discussions of such are certainly suitable on Stack Overflow.